# product of two polynomials in sigma notation?

Tags: polynomials, summation

Say I have polynomials $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^np_{k}x^k$ and I have $q(x) = \sum_{l=0}^nq_{l}x^l$. I have to write their product in sigma notation. That is $p(x)q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}A_{k}x^k$ and I have to find $A_{k}$. I have tried writing out the terms for one n = 1 and n = 2. for n = 1 I get:

$p_{0}q_{0} + x(p_{0}q_{1} + p_{1}q_{0}) + x^2p_{1}q_{1}$

and for n = 2 I get:

$p_{0}q_{0} + x(p_{0}q_{1} + p_{1}q_{0}) + x^2(p_{0}q_{2} + p_{1}q_{1} + p_{2}q_{0}) + x^3(p_{1}q_{2} + p_{2}q_{1}) + x^4p_{2}q_{2}$

I've figured out that the sum of the indices of p and q always equal to k. However, I can't seem to put this into sigma notation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2215119

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k\sum_{j=\max({k-n},0)}^{\min(k,n)}p_jq_{k-j}$$

If you define $p_j=q_j=0$ for $j>n$ you can just write

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}x^k\sum_{j=0}^{k}p_jq_{k-j}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a little confused about the second one. Say we have n = 1. But then, when i have k = 2, won't there be $x^2(p_{0}q_{2} + p_{1}q_{1} + p_{2}q_{0})$ where it should instead be $x^2p_{1}q_{1}$?

Comment: If $n=1$ then the term with $x^2$ is $p_1q_1x^2$. With the second notation is $(p_0q_2+p_1q_1+p_2q_0)x^2$ but $p_2=q_2=0$.